# how do you transform a date that's storred as a type long (epoch time) into a dateOptionalTime in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field in my database that's stored as Epoch time, which is a `long`. I'm trying to get Elasticsearch to recognize this field as what it *actually* is: a date. Once indexed by Elasticsearch, I want it to be of type `dateOptionalTime`.

My thinking is that I need to apply a `transform` to convert the Epoch `long` into a string `date`.

On my index, I have a mapping that specifies the `type` for my field as `date` with a `format` of `dateOptionalTime`. Finally, this timestamp is in all of my docs, so I've added my (attempted) mapping to `_default_`.

The code:

```
'_default_', {
            '_all': {'enabled': 'true'},
            'dynamic_templates': [
                { "date_fixer" : {
                    "match": "my_timestamp",
                    "mapping": {
                        "transform": {
                            "script": "ctx._source['my_timestamp'] = new Date(ctx._source['my_timestamp']).toString()"
                        },
                        'type': "date",
                    }
                }
            }]
    }
```

I'm brand new to Elastic, so I'll walk through what I *think* is happening.

1. I'm setting this to type `_default_` which will apply this to all new types Elastic encounters.
2. I set `_all` to enabled. I want Elastic to use the default mapping for all types with the exception of my timestamp field.
3. finally, I add my dynamic template that (a) converts the long into a date, and (b) applies a mapping to the timestamp field explicitly saying that it *is* a `date`

**The Problem:**

When I try to add my data to the index, I get the following exception.

```
TransportError(400, u'MapperParsingException[failed to parse [my_timestamp]]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[unknown property [$date]]; ')
```

My data looks like:

```
{
    "timestamp": 8374747594, 
    "owner": "text", 
    "some_more": {
        "key": "val", 
        "key": "val"
    }
}
```

Comment: How is your data getting into elasticsearch?  If you set it as a date type there, it should end up in elasticsearch as a date.

Comment: Hmm.. I suppose I could scrub all the data before I put it in, however, should I be ale to simply write a rule in Elastic that tells it how to treat this specific input?